# Flat bands and localization in real space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

When reading [this](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature26154) paper I came across the following claim:

> From a band-theory point of view, the flat bands should have localized wavefunction profiles in real space

Is there a rigorous proof of this statement? So far I've only seen a hand-waving argument that goes like this: a flat band means the effective mass of the particle is infinite, i.e. it's very heavy and can't move - hence the localization in real space.

Presumably, this can be shown with a Fourier transform. I know that if we start with a localized wavefunction, i.e. something like $\Psi(x,t)=\delta(x-a)$ (where $a$ is the site) we arrive at the following momentum representation:

$$
\Phi\left(p,t\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{-\frac{ipa}{\hbar}}
$$

However I'm not sure how this representation leads to the dispersion relation of a flat band ($E(k)=\mathrm{const}$). Doesn't it depend on the Hamiltonian of the system?

Comment: If all the modes making up a band are degenerate then arbitrary rotations amongst the modes produce eigenmodes. The statement that the band is localised is surely not a statement about the eigenmodes (which you are free to choose), but simply that the group velocity is zero.

Comment: i did not read the paper but i guess they talk about the  gapless edge states am I rigth? and if it is the case, the explanation is not that simple as flat band=localized state  it is more sophisticated

Comment: As already commented below by @ComptonScattering, bands with non-trivial Chern number cannot have (exponentially) localized Wannier functions, so at least if the statement is read in this way, it seems incorrect. (See, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04696) Of course, the quote is out of context, so it is hard to tell what is meant.

Answer (score 7):

The quoted statement is not precise. A better formulation might be

> From a band-theory point of view, flat bands **lead to dispersionless evolution** of wavefunctions.
> In most cases, they **admit localized wavefunction profiles** in real space.

Flat bands are said to be *dispersionless* in the following sense: the group velocity for wave packets is $dE(k)/dk = 0$ and therefore each wave packet preserves its form under time evolution. If it is initially localized it stays localized forever. This can be easily shown using the Fourier transform:

$$
  \psi(t,\vec x) = \int dk\, e^{-i\vec k\vec x} \tilde \psi(t, \vec k) = \int dk\, e^{-i\vec k\vec x} e^{-i E(\vec k) t} \tilde \psi(0, \vec k)
$$
Now if $E(\vec k) = E_0$ then
$$
  \psi(t,\vec x) = e^{-i E_0 t} \int dk\, e^{-i\vec k\vec x} \tilde \psi(0, \vec k) = e^{-i E_0 t} \psi(0, \vec x)
$$
which means that the form of $|\psi(t,\vec x)|$ stays constant in time.
The flat band is a property of the Hamiltonian. But once the Hamiltonian admits a flat band then this flat band is always dispersionless in the same way, independently of further details of the Hamiltonian.

The question about the localization in real space goes further and is related to the fact whether well localized Wannier functions can be constructed for the given Hamiltonian. In most cases, [Wannier functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wannier_function#Localization) are exponentially localized but the general criterion is not known. The papers [arXiv:2104.01236](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.01236) and    [arXiv:2010.06782](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.06782), however, offer several examples of systems with flat bands and localization.

Comment: Could you comment on how non trivial topological indices effect your more refined claim? Specifically, consider a band with a non trivial Chern number. A band with a non trivial Chern number does not admit a localised basis. Moreover, the band may be flattened by adding localised terms to the Hamiltonian and without closing a band gap, and thus preserving the non trivial Chern number. Is this a counter example to your claim?

Comment: Can you show that the wavepacket stays localized forever if $dE(k)/dk=0$?

Comment: @grjj3 I have edited my answer and added the calculation you are asking for.

Comment: @ComptonScattering Could you provide a particular example? I have added the calculation to my answer which is pretty straightforward. I do not see how this would be affected by non-zero Chern number. Here, arxiv.org/abs/1205.2245, they speak about "almost dispersionless bands with higher Chern numbers" (and I guess, the "almost dispersionless" is related to "almost flat" bands).

Comment: It is a lattice. You have to start with a Bloch state to cope with the periodic structure.

Comment: The incompatibility of non trivial Chern numbers, and an exponentially localised Wannier basis is well known (see eg Bernevig and Hughes). The reason being that (by Paley Weiner theorem) an exponentially localised Wannier basis implies the existence of a smooth gauge in k-space, and hence therefore that the Chern number is zero. Thus a band with non zero Chern number is a counter example to your reformulated claim, that a flat band admits a basis of localised states, but is not a counter example to your calculation, which shows a different claim, that wavepackets do not evolve.

Comment: Very good point by @ComptonScattering, thanks. I can re-edit the claim to say either "flat bands admit localized wavefunctions provided the band Chern number vanishes" or "flat bands admit dispersionless evolution of wavefunctions". Which is better?

Comment: @Nikodem How does re-editing the statement without changing the proof make the latter more correct? Where are you using that the band has a trivial Chern number. -- Also, it seems that your answer has not much to do with the question: You argue that states stay dispersionless, which might be necessary, but logically is not sufficient, for localized eigenstates.

Comment: Than you @NorbertSchuch for you comment. I weakened my answer. We deal here with two questions: 1. How flat band leads to dispersionless evolution, 2. How flat band leads to localization. There is a subtle difference between these two points, as ComptonScattering already pointed, and without deeper analysis of the Hamiltonian (cf. Chern number) the second question cannot be answered. It can be however loosely noted that in most practical situations, i.e. whenever Wannier functions can be exponentially localized, 1. leads to 2..

Comment: Given that the paper (I believe) deals with topological bands, it might not be one of those "practical situations". (Differently speaking, I have the feeling that the answer slightly misses the question ... though this might also be in part due to the question being unclear.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, the question is quite unclear and my answer is an attempt to make the best of it. The comments about the heavy particle and Fourier transform are not really useful. The quoted sentence from the paper is fuzzy ("should have") and strictly seen not correct (as flat bands *may or may not* lead to localized wavefunction profiles in real space). In order to improve over that, I guess, one should post another question about the conditions on localization of Wannier functions. But there will be no clear answer as this problem is still being investigated...

Answer (score 2):

If we look at this from the point of view of the [tight-binding approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding), the band width is proportional to the hopping integral, i.e., in one dimension
$$
H=E_0\sum_n|n\rangle\langle n | - \Delta\sum_n\left(|n\rangle\langle n+1| + |n+1\rangle\langle n|\right),\\
E(k)=E_0-2\Delta\cos(ka)
$$
If the band is flat, it means that $\Delta=0$, i.e., there is no hopping, that is the wave functions are localized.

**Remark**
Note that this argument can be trivially generalized to a lattice in any number of dimensions: without hopping all the sites have the same energy - thus, we can construct the Bloch states which have the same energy for any $\mathbf{k}$. In case we have atoms with different site energies in a unit cell, we well have several flat bands.

Comment: This is a single basis tight-binding picture. If you include multi-bases, the argument will be different.

Comment: @ytlu please expand your comment a bit - it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: Multi-bases the energy equation will become a matrix. The condition for the existence of flat-band is not obvious.

Comment: @ytlu It doesn't matter: without hopping all the sites have the same energy, or a set of energies, so it is easy to construct Bloch states, which will have the same energy for all $\mathbf{k}$.

Comment: No. It happens that the the hopping constant is not zero, but flat band appeared in some segments of the band structure.

Comment: @ytlu not sure how this is related to my answer or to your previous comment. If you want to improve my answer - please be more clear. If you think that this answer is wrong - write your own.

Comment: @RogerVadim   Your answer is alright, of course.

Comment: This answer is pretty wrong. First, also Hamiltonians with non-zero hopping integral can have flat bands, see e.g. Lieb lattices. Second, the phenomenon of wavefunction localization is not due to vanishing of the hopping parameter $\Delta$ because this would be totally trivial. See my answer for an alternative attempt to address this question.

Comment: My answer may not cover all cases where the band is flat, but it is certainly not wrong - not if one knows to construct Bloch states from lattice orbitals or Wannier functions, since from there the argument is very straighforward. Your answer does not seem to address the core of the question: is the orbital licalized and how to demonstrate it.

Comment: @RogerVadim OK, maybe I should rather use the word "misleading" instead of "wrong". In your example the localization is a consequence of no-hopping ($\Delta = 0$). But this is not the essence of localization in flat bands. This example is just too trivial and makes a wrong impression that localization is *due to* no-hopping. If we go to 2D we see (e.g. in Lieb lattices) that one can have hopping ($\Delta \neq 0$) and flat band and localization at the same time.

Comment: @Nikodem - my answer directly addresses the attempts in the OP to find the localized states via Fourier transform of the band (which are incorrect, since one can get only the envelope function this way) - no more and no less than that. It was to give the OP a better perspective. Your answer touches on the question in the OP only in the last paragraph. Btw, linear band, $\epsilon_k=ck$ would be also dispersionless. If you can show the localization of states in your answer, I will be glad to show good sportsmanship and upvote it.

Comment: @RogerVadim I cannot show localization for a flat band because it is not guaranteed, in general. This is related to the fact that the Wannier functions may fail to be exponentially localized. One needs to know more details of the Hamiltonian to answer this question. I put a link to Wikipedia passage on that topic from which one can read "the general conditions are not established, and are the subject of ongoing research".

Comment: @Nikodem If you work in this field, why not put a link to a real scientific paper, instead of wikipedia? After all, the question is based on a scientific paper, which makes a different claim - it is not a layman discussion.

Comment: @RogerVadim I would love to but I do not know any good overview. The subject is complex and the answer depends strongly on the details (of the Hamiltonian). There is some useful discussion below my answer, referring to Chern numbers.

Comment: @Nikodem why do you insist on exponential decay? This is not a disorder problem, but rather  one about lattice structure.

Comment: @RogerVadim So what kind of localization do you mean?

Comment: @Nikodem localization on lattice sites. In general case, this is perhaps not true for all the lattice sites, but for a sublattice or superposition of sublattice states.

Comment: @RogerVadim I understand. The two papers I have added to my answer address exactly this -- localization in sublattices. They give many examples. But I don't know any general theory.